# Pipenv not creating Pipfile and not creating environment in right location

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pipenv, python-venv

I'm trying to use pipenv to create a virtual environment for my python program. I have a folder on my desktop (we'll call it 'project') where I `cd` to. So basically I'm in `C:\Users\my_user\Desktop\project\`.

I write `pipenv shell`, upon which the I get:

```
Using C:/Python39/python.exe (3.9.0) to create virtualenv...
[   =] Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.9.0.final.0-64 in 446ms
  creator CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Users\my_user\.virtualenvs\my_user-GweeH6qV, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.2.4, setuptools==51.0.0, wheel==0.36.2
  activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: C:\Users\my_user\.virtualenvs\my_user-GweeH6qV
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.746]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

(my_user-GweeH6qV) C:\Users\my_user>
```

Basically, it does make a virtual environment, but I notice that my Pipfile and Pipfile.lock (as well as a bunch of other files) are not in my project directory, but rather in the directory `C:\Users\my_user`.

Why is this the case? No matter what I do I can't seem to get my environment, and my pipfiles to be in the project directory on my desktop.

A possible reason for this could have been that I did `easy_install.exe pip` (or something along those lines) to install pip because I was having issues with it a while back.

Here are some of the things I've tried:

1. running `pipenv install ________` rather than `pipenv shell`
2. moving the project folder to a different folder (downloads, documents) and running `pipenv shell` from there.
3. Putting a folder in my project folder and then running `pipenv shell` from that folder. This actually did work although I dont want my pipenv to be in a subfolder of project, I want it to be in the project folder itself.

Comment: after `pipenv shell`, do `pipenv install <package>` inside the project folder, then it will modify the pipfile

Comment: @sahasrara62 yes, but that modifies the pipfile in ```C:\Users\my_user``` rather than ```C:\Users\my_user\Desktop\project```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the problem by simply deleting the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock files that were in `C:\Users\my_user`, and then in my `C:\Users\my_user\Desktop\project` running `pipenv install <package>`.

The reason for the issue was most likely that at some point I probably opened a pipenv in `C:\Users\my_user`, and since pipenv does not allow for virtual environments within virtual environments, it would not let me create one inside `C:\Users\my_user\Desktop\project`.

Answer (score 3):

After deleting the `Pipfile` and the `Pipfile.lock` from the home directory `~/` I was able to create a new virtual environment without conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted pipfile and pipfile.lock in all instances on my machine. Then I went on terminal and uninstalled pipenv:
`pip uninstall pipenv`
and then reinstalled pipenv:
`pip install pipenv`
That seemed to do the trick for me